# Finding an inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd like to make sure I'm doing things right, my answer looks a little funny.

I have the following function:

$$g(x) = 3 + x + e^x$$

I am trying to find $g^{-1}(x)$, so I replace $g(x)$ with $y$ and switch it with $x$ to get:

$$x = 3+y + e^y$$

I get y on a single side and end up with:

$$ g^{-1}(x) = -3-e^y + x $$

Is this correct? Should I have done something with logarithms to get rid of $-e^y$? How could I do it without also transforming the y on the other side?

Thanks!

Comment: Your method is incorrect; this function has no nice inverse.

Comment: According to wolfram alpha the function passes the horizontal line test.

Comment: @Newb, quite right, it does have an inverse, just not a nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is a 1-1 map of $\mathbb R$ onto itself, so it does have an inverse $g^{-1}$ that is also a map of $\mathbb R$ onto itself. Unfortunately, it is known that it is not possible to write this inverse explicitly in terms of elementary functions as you wish to do.